# Embedding video into richtext editor Field gives an ERROR: Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, rich-text, office-365-developer, video-richmedia

How can I embed Video's from my Office365 /Portal/Hub in **SharePoint-hosted App-part**.

I am getting an error when I try to get the video or display video in my app-part, error message looks like:

> Refused to display 
>   'https://Test.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/VideoEmb…f8-4dfb-8b16-c849ab7acf16&width=853&height=480&autoPlay=true&showInfo=true' 
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

And in my App-part .aspx page I already have defined "AllowFraming":

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />
```

one way i was thinking to maybe define this line of code above in master page but then its gonna be security issue for clickjacking enabling this.

any help solving this issue will be appreciated...

Comment: Try adding &output=embed to the end of the url and check